# MySQL, select * while replacing text in certain column (before output)

Tags: mysql, select, replace

I have a table with some 'HTML code' in one of the columns..  (an iframe/embed code to be exact)

We have a little 'table viewer' app here at work.. and when I go to the table and select * on it.. it parse the results in a table.  (hence rendering the iframe/embed code)  --- YUK!   (and it takes forever to load)

How can I do a SELECT  (not update/not permanent) statement on this table while selection ALL..  but also replacing some of the text in this embed column?

My goal/thought is to select *, replace the text 'iframe' to be 'xframe' or something.. so I only get the 'TEXT' in that column.. (and it doesnt parse in the table/display view)

I have tried slight variations of this:  (didnt work)

```
SELECT * REPLACE('mp3_title', 'iframe', 'xframe') FROM table_name;
```

I tried this as well (mp3_new col was empty)

```
SELECT id, topic, title, vimeo_id, video_length, speaker_first, speaker_last, speaker_designation, description, active, replace(mp3_title, 'iframe','xframe') as mp3_new
FROM table_name;
```

### update:

I apologize for my rush to post..

seems it was working. but I wasnt thinking enough to replace the <  >  brackets!!

this works fine:

```
SELECT id, topic, title, vimeo_id, video_length, speaker_first, speaker_last, speaker_designation, description, active, replace(mp3_title, '<iframe','^iframe') as mp3_new
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: You also changed what your original effort was

Comment: @dbmitch

how so?

The 'effort' (so to speak) was the question.. (as in how to achieve it)

Answer (score 0):

Your first try should work fine - probably just a syntax error

Use

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(mp3_title, 'iframe', 'xframe') AS new_title FROM vimeo_videos;
```

> **Explanation:**
>
> remove quotes around fieldname, add comma after * to separate fields